# How do I match the text of two cells to one cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am combining multiple data sources that list employee names differently ("Last, First", "First Last", "Last First", etc.) into one workbook and thus one table.  I want to avoid spending a lot of time manipulating the imported data.

I want to use a formula that will tell me if someone's name is in the row (A) regardless of how the name is displayed.  Below is a formula that I was using, however it does not guarantee that the first and last name are matched in the same cell/row.  (Yellow highlight indicates examples that are incorrect.)

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

Formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH("*"&C3&"*",$A$2:$A$6,0)>=0,IF(MATCH("*"&D3&"*",$A$2:$A$6,0)>=0,1,0)),0)
```

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a data structure issue. One approach is to make a "match: tab or workbook.  Put in the names from all sources. Then use a formula to transform into a like format.  This may involve de-dupe and formatting steps.  Attempting to do this inside a formula or a macro, is like trying to fix a leaky roof with duct tape.  You are just waiting for the next leak to spring so y'all can go duct tape it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C3,Certified))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D3,Certified)))
```

Where `Certified` is your list in column A.

If Case Sensitivity helps (meaning fewer false positives without increasing false negatives), as it would for certain examples pointed out by @Scott in his comment below, substitute `FIND` for `SEARCH` in the formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND(C3,Certified))*ISNUMBER(FIND(D3,Certified)))
```

If you need to ensure whole word matching, I would recommend a VBA solution.

[image]

The `ISNUMBER(..` functions return an array of `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether Last Name or First Name are found in a row.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C3,Certified)) --> {FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D3,Certified)) --> {TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}
```

When the two arrays are multiplied together, they well return a `1` for `TRUE` in the same place (same row) and `0` for any other combination.

In the above, they will return `{0;0;0;0;0}`

For row with `Carl James`, we see

```
{FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE}
{FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE}
```

which when multiplied --> `{0;0;1;0;0}`

Hence, the `SUMPRODUCT` will return a count of the number of rows that have both the Last Name and First Name matching the row being tested in your second table.  This will also pick up if someone has been entered more than once in your first table.

Comment: Do you actually have this working?  I can't get it to work; it seems to me that `SEARCH` doesn't accept a range or a region as an argument (I'm using Excel 2013).

Comment: @Scott Yes.  If you use a range as the `within_text` argument for `SEARCH`, it will return an array of either `#VALUE!` or the number matching the result.  eg:`=SEARCH(C3,Certified)` ►  `{#VALUE!;1;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!}`.  And it has worked that way for versions well before 2013.

Comment: OK; shame on me for trying pieces of your formula rather than the whole thing (D’oh!).  Like [the other Scott](//superuser.com/q/1116457/150988#1116460), you risk getting a lot of false positives from simply searching for names (as substrings).  Your formula returns 1 for “John Shelly” if “Shelley Johnson” is in Column A, and likewise for “Toni An” if there is an “Antonio”.  It also returns 1 for “Rose Enfeld” if *your* name is in Column A.

Comment: @Scott  Yes, with irregular data, you have to weigh the issue of false positives vs false negatives. That's a decision for the OP.  So far as your last two examples, that can be avoided by using `FIND` instead of `SEARCH`.  Again, without knowing all the details of the data variability, it is difficult to craft the most useful solution.  But I will add the suggestion of using `FIND` to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Search for both names at the same time.  You will need to do two searches one with the first name in front and another with the last name in front:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*" & C3 & "*" & D3 & "*",A:A,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH("*" & D3 & "*" & C3 & "*",A:A,0))),1,0)
```

The `ISNUMBER` returns TRUE when a match is found.  If no match is found the MATCH will return an error(a non-number).

[image]

Comment: You risk getting a lot of false positives from those wildcards.  Your formula returns 1 for “John Shelly” if “Shelley Johnson” is in Column A, and likewise for “Toni An” if there is an “Antonio”.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Scott Craner’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1116457/150988#1116460), I suggest

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C3 & " " & D3,A:A,0)), ISNUMBER(MATCH(D3 & " " & C3,A:A,0)),
                ISNUMBER(MATCH(D3 & ", " & C3,A:A,0))),1,0)
```

(Type it all on one line.) 
This looks for one of the three possible presentations
that you show in the question:

- “Firstname Lastname” (`C3 & " " & D3`)
- “Lastname Firstname” (`D3 & " " & C3`)
- “Lastname, Firstname” (`D3 & ", " & C3`)

without risking a lot of false positives that come from using wildcards (`*`). 
Of course, this risks getting false negatives
if the names are entered in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Move your summary cells over and then use text to columns to split it up by comma and space, treating them as separate delimiters. Add a column to reconcatenate `=IF(C2="",CONCATENATE(A2," ",B2),CONCATENATE(C2," ",A2))`.

[image]

Comment: (1) There’s no such function as `CONCAT`; I presume you mean `CONCATENATE`.  (2) I don’t understand what you think you’re accomplishing by `=CONCATENATE(B2," ",A2,C2)`.  (3) How does this handle the problem where John Smith is present in Column A as “Smith, John”?

Comment: @Scott  'CONCAT` is a function introduced, I believe, in Excel 2016

Comment: Good to know. But the question is tagged [Excel 2007].

Comment: @Scott I missed the 2007. Concat is really nice upgrade. I revised my answer with a new solution using `concatenate` instead. By splitting your data with text to columns you can know where the first and last names will fall and then combine them via an if statement.

Comment: I usually use concatenate and spend a couple days putting all of the employee names in the same order, then use pivots and filters to copy / paste the names into the appropriate report.  I was trying to avoid spending so much time working on this quarterly report.